# Manipulating local or external variable within NDSolve

Tags: numerical-integration

I am wanting to save and use the value of a variable within `NDSolve[]` but without that variable being part of the equation itself.

Code below (ODE for the Leaky Integrate-and-Fire neuron) expresses what I want to do, with the value for the end of the refractory period updated within a `WhenEvent[]` statement.

Unfortunately it doesn't work and the error message suggests why not - but I don't know the solution though I am sure a simple one must exist.

```
trest = 0;
With[{τ = 10, R = 1, Jm = 1.5, vthresh = 1, vreset = 0, v0 = 0, tref = 3 },
 lif = NDSolve[{v'[t] == If[ t >= trest, -(v[t] - Jm R)/τ, 0], 
        v[0] == v0, 
        WhenEvent[ v[t] >= vthresh, {v[t] -> vreset, trest -> Evaluate[ t + tref ] } ]},
        v[t], {t, 0, 60}] ]
```

> ```
> NDSolve::wenset: Warning: the rule trest->Evaluate[t+3] will not directly set 
> the state because the left-hand side is not a list of state variables. >>
> ```

I realise that this can be done by adding another variable into the ODE, making its time `derivative == 0` and just changing its value within the `WhenEvent[]` statement but this is rather messy and has potential to confuse the ODE solver.

Comment: Why do you think that it _"has potential to confuse the ODE solver"_? Take a look at what DiscreteVariables do.

Comment: because having another variable in the problem with a zero derivative and then changing its value as a step function will have an impact on certain solution methods and their error/stiffness estimates

Comment: DiscreteVariables doesn't help, because it doesn't help to save the value that updates as you step through time.  A solution that does this but needs the auxiliary variable defined within the system is:                                                     `With[{\[Tau] = 10, R = 10, Jm = 0.7, vthresh = 1, vreset = 0, v0 = 0, 
  tref = 2 },
 lif = NDSolve[{v'[t] == If[ t >= trest[t], -(v[t] - Jm R)/\[Tau], 0],
     v[0] == v0, trest'[t] == 0, trest[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[
     v[t] >= vthresh, {v[t] -> vreset, 
      trest[t] -> Evaluate[ t + tref] } ]}, {v[t], trest[t]}, {t, 0, 
    60}]]`

Comment: any other thoughts?  the above solution works but defining the auxiliary variable within the ODE feels wrong - surely there is a way of making WhenEvent[] save a value to a variable outside of the ODE itself?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to make `trest` one of the [`DiscreteVariables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteVariables.html).

```
Clear[trest]
With[{τ = 10, R = 1, Jm = 1.5, vthresh = 1, vreset = 0, v0 = 0, tref = 3}, 
 lif = NDSolve[{v'[t] == 
     Piecewise[{{-(v[t] - Jm R)/τ, t >= trest[t]}}, 0], 
    v[0] == v0, trest[0] == 0,
    WhenEvent[v[t] >= vthresh, {v[t] -> vreset, trest[t] -> t + tref}]},
 {v, trest}, {t, 0, 60}, DiscreteVariables -> {trest}]];

ListLinePlot[v /. First[lif], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]